# Background-repeat или обычное изображение

Tags: css, браузер

Есть фоновая картинка заданная как `backround-image` в css - весит 27кб.
Есть "паттерн" который можно задать так же через css и "размножить" по блоку `background-repeat`. Весит 113 байт.

Какой из вариантов будет быстрее грузиться чисто теоретически? В одном случае нужно просто загрузить изображение большего объема, во втором изображение меньше, но браузеру его нужно "Размножить" на блок.

Comment: Чисто теоретически размноженный будет грузится быстрее, во всех смыслах. Но технически обрисовать принцип нагрузки кейса не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Произвести профайлинг рендеринга довольно трудно. Но это и не нужно. Вполне может оказаться, что разницы нет или она незначительна.

А если под словом "грузиться" вы подразумеваете загрузку изображения с сервера, то тут точно разница будет минимальная. Вы можете легко убедится в этом сами посмотрев timlene в инструментах разработчика брузера Google Chrome.

Метод заполнения повторениями используют все реже потому, что его часто можно заменить чистым CSS3 без использования изображений вообще, например используя repeating-linear-gradient как упомянул в коментариях @Artem Gorlachev

Comment: Свиду профайлинг провести достаточно легко в хроме. А можно пример последнего абзаца? У меня что-то жуткое и явно тяжелое в плане рендеринга представляется в голове.

Comment: Погуглил, тк разговор про мелкие элементы, нашел `repeating-linear-gradient`, это как раз то, о чем я и спрашивал)